# Pcap.Net PacketCommunicator.Dispose() close my application without any error

Tags: c#, pcap.net

I am using `Pcap.Net` take `Pcap` File and transmit all it's packet through my machine `Network Adapter`.
So in order to do that i am using the code example [Sending packets using Send Buffer](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/wiki/Pcap.Net-Tutorial-Sending-Packets):

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string file = @"C:\file_1.pcap";
            string file2 = @"C:\file_2.pcap";
            // Retrieve the device list from the local machine
            IList<LivePacketDevice> allDevices = LivePacketDevice.AllLocalMachine;

            // Take the selected adapter
            PacketDevice selectedOutputDevice = allDevices[1];

            SendPackets(selectedOutputDevice, file);
            SendPackets(selectedOutputDevice, file2);
        }

        static void SendPackets(PacketDevice selectedOutputDevice, string file)
        {
            // Retrieve the length of the capture file
            long capLength = new FileInfo(file).Length;

            // Chek if the timestamps must be respected
            bool isSync = false;

            // Open the capture file
            OfflinePacketDevice selectedInputDevice = new OfflinePacketDevice(file);

            using (PacketCommunicator inputCommunicator = selectedInputDevice.Open(65536, PacketDeviceOpenAttributes.Promiscuous, 1000))
            {
                using (PacketCommunicator outputCommunicator = selectedOutputDevice.Open(100, PacketDeviceOpenAttributes.Promiscuous, 1000))
                {
                    // Allocate a send buffer
                    using (PacketSendBuffer sendBuffer = new PacketSendBuffer((uint)capLength))
                    {
                         // Fill the buffer with the packets from the file
                        Packet packet;
                        while (inputCommunicator.ReceivePacket(out packet) == PacketCommunicatorReceiveResult.Ok)
                        {
                            //outputCommunicator.SendPacket(packet);
                            sendBuffer.Enqueue(packet);
                        }

                        // Transmit the queue
                        outputCommunicator.Transmit(sendBuffer, isSync);                        
                        inputCommunicator.Dispose();
                    }

                    outputCommunicator.Dispose();
                }

                //inputCommunicator.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

In order to send packet `Pcap.Net` offers 2 ways:

1. Send buffer.
2. Send each packet using `SendPacket()`.

Now after finish to send my 2 files (like in my example) i want to use the `Dispose()` to free resources.

when using the first option all works fine and this finish to handle my 2 `Pcap` files.

When using the second option `SendPacket()` (currently in my code example this is as a comments) after the first file finish my application is closing and not reach to the second file.
I try it also in `Console Application` and in `WPF` and in both cases same result.
With `UI` (WPF) my application `GUI` just close without any error.

Any suggestions what could cause this ?

Comment: You don't need to explicitly call `dispose()` because you are using the `using` statement. [`using` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: When play a lot of files in endless lop i notice that my memory is increment, at the start my application memory usage is about 70MB and after a night this usage is 180 MB so i wonder if i need to implement here Dispose method, i know that my SendPackets method is doing the work and i don't have any other things that can be the root of this memory lack, is it possible that the open file that i am dong over and over  responsible for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `using` keyword it means you implicitly call `Dispose()` at the end of the scope.

If you call `Dispose()` explicitly as well, it means you call `Dispose()` twice on the same instance, which is likely to crash your program.